# CMS to update just one section of an existing site

Tags: php, content-management-system, simplepie

say I have a static site that contains such page:

http://example.com/events.php

I'd like to use a CMS in order to update only that page in a blog-fashion, i.e. multiple articles, pagination and single pages for single articles. I was thinking about a way in order to achieve such result. I recall Blogger.com had a feature like that but I can't seem to find it anymore. Or maybe I could set up a WP/Tumblr and grab its feed via SimplePie.

What would you suggest?

Many thanks,

-N.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know any PHP or SQL? You can build your own simple CMS (Content Management System) using these server side languages.

If you need to use FTP, then it is not really a CMS and it would seem as if you would be editing the pages directly, unless you update a single conf file.

Using SQL, you can setup an ACP (Administrative Control Panel where you will be able to change all content dynamically, depending on how you structure your pages.

See [this link](http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/) if you wish to learn how to build your own SIMPLE CMS.

Because you have your own custom website, it will be next-to-impossible to be able to find a pre built system that will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry, by FTP I meant that Blogger.com pushed contents via FTP, but it still used its own web-based interface for you to write.

Comment: So that page that you view to actually edit your posts is part of their own CMS. When you click post, it will save your changes to an SQL server. When a user browses to a page, the server will pull the information out of the SQL database, and place it into your web page.